# Java graphing Numbers of objects

Tags: java, image, list, graph, png

Hey I have a program that has a list like this

```
List<Entity> entities;
```

and theres a loop were each entity acts and does things and I want to be able to make a graph(outputed as a .png) of the amounts of each Entity per turn in a line chart form
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Is this a question or a joke?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at something like http://processing.org/.